# Forced to commit shirk at school

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, forgiveness, jahannam, school

Hey so I have 2 problems:

1.in one of my subjects, we have to organize something for this years halloween and I have to participate too.
We’re gonna go to 3rd graders and teach them halloween vocabulary. And as far as I know, halloween is a shirk/pagan holiday.I am extremely uncomfortable with the whole situation but I’m obviously not allowed to not participate, will I be held accountable for this?

2.in another subject, we’re gonna watch a movie soon and I did some research because I was curious about the content, now I saw that there is gonna be music (obviously) and even shirk in the lyrics. I don’t know what to do since I can’t just stop going to school and my parents wouldn’t allow me to stay home, but if I watch the movie knowing that the songs in it have shirk, will I be held accountable? I would want to stay home for all the lessons that we watch movies but I can’t.

Comment: As a student, usually for this kind of stuff, just talking to your teacher about this should resolve the issue. Or a simple letter from your parents should help this out. Don't stress about it, and Allah will help you be guided to the right path.

Comment: When talking to your teacher like @NanoAdam said, make sure to bring up your religion. Do this multiple times until the teacher agrees, and if the teacher continually refuses to let you skip these activities, go to the principal.

Comment: Thanks for answering but my problem is that I live in a non-muslim country and my parents wouldn’t really care to write a letter. There are also other muslims in the class and they’re participating (I’m not justifying it though because I think they’re non-practicing). I think if I did that everyone would laugh at me and I also have anxiety which makes it worse to talk to people. The teacher in situation 1 also asked if everyone is okay with the topic halloween and I was too scared to say anything so I just agreed but I feel really bad now.

Comment: Also, I’m not sure I have to participate in the actual event, I think I have to write the invitation letters but since I’m participating I think that counts as shirk as well?

Comment: It would help if we knew exactly which non-Muslim country.

Answer (score 1):

A school should not force you to do things in which you do not want to do for **religious** reasons. Talk to a member of staff to resolve this. If you try your best to resolve it and they still force you to do the activity, keep a **low profile** and **don't engage in more than is needed of you**, then Allahu a'lam if it counts as a sin. This is not your **intention**, though and in Islam, you intend that matters. There are ahadith and there are Quranic verses that support this, like:

> “There are four types of people: one is a man whom Allah has given knowledge and wealth. He acts concerning his wealth based on his knowledge. Another person says that if Allah had given him similar to what He gave the first man, he would have acted in the same fashion. The reward for both of them will be the same. A third person is one, whom Allah gives wealth but He does not give knowledge. Therefore, he spends money according to his desire. Another man says that if Allah had given him, what He had given that person, he would have acted in the same manner. These two will have the same burden upon them.” [Ibn Majah with a good chain]

> “Verily, all actions are but driven by intention and for everyone is what he intended.” [Bukhari and Muslim]

It tells us that even if you **do not have the means to do something** if you want to do it, it still counts as a haram / halal. If you are put in a situation like this, try your best to **avoid the haram activities** within (for example, drinking alcohol in a celebration or eating pork in a restaurant etc.)

If you are **helpless**, then it would not count against you. Allah is the **most just being that can ever exist**, and he would **not** put you in such a situation and force a sin to be recorded if you cannot help it. That is **morally wrong**, holding somebody accountable for something they **can't** **help**.

Allah knows best. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks but I also said this to the other people who commented: I live in a non-muslim country and my parents wouldn’t really care to write a letter. There are other muslims in the class and they’re participating (I think they’re non-practicing and don’t know it’s bad). The teacher from the halloween project asked if everyone is okay with it and I didn’t say anything because I have anxiety so I just went along with it,but I feel terrible now. I don’t really think I can say anything because they would laugh at me but I’m scared now bc I don’t wanna go to hell